# Why is this hook jumping to wrong address?

Tags: c++, assembly, hook

So i am currently learning about hooking and injection and build a little test application for myself. What i am doing in there is:

1. Allocating some memory inside the process (using `VirtualAllocEx`)
2. Writing code to this code-cave (using `WriteProcessMemory`)
3. Hooking a function inside the app to jump to this code-cave

Now i have some problems which i am unsure of why they occur. 
My code for creating the cave is this:

```
    DWORD procID = GetCurrentProcessId();
    HANDLE procHandle = OpenProcess((PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION), false, procID);
    if (procHandle == NULL) {
        std::cout << "OpenProcess failed..." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD leng = (unsigned int)dynASM_end - (unsigned int)dynASM;
    leng += 270;

    LPVOID allocAddr = VirtualAllocEx(procHandle, NULL, leng, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    std::cout << "BaseAddr: " << allocAddr << std::endl;

    int check = WriteProcessMemory(procHandle, (void*)((char*)allocAddr + 0x10E), dynASM, leng - 270, NULL);
    unsigned int bExec = 1;
    check = WriteProcessMemory(procHandle, allocAddr, &bExec, sizeof(unsigned int), NULL);
    if (check) {
        std::cout << "Successfully written asm to process!" << std::endl;
    }
```

Now this is very basic. `VirtualAllocEx` always returns `0x00030000`, is this possible?
This is my simple assembly code:

```
void testCall()
{
    std::cout << "Hook worked!" << std::endl;
}

__declspec(naked) void dynASM()
{
    __asm {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        call testCall
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
    }
}

__declspec(naked) void dynASM_end()
{
}
```

I believe i can call the function `testCall` this way, can't i? This is the code which i put into the codecave as you can see above.

Now i have a offset to a function inside another class in which i want to hook. This function only consists of:

```
__declspec(naked) void Core::HookFunc()
{
    __asm {
        mov edi, edi
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp

        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
    }
}
```

And i try to hook like this:

```
DWORD hookFuncOffset = 0x14510;
DWORD jumpTo = (DWORD)((char*)allocAddr + 0x10E);
DWORD baseAddr = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

BYTE* finalAddr = (BYTE*)((DWORD)baseAddr + hookFuncOffset);

DWORD oldProtect, bkpProtect, relAdr;
VirtualProtect(finalAddr, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);

relAdr = (DWORD)(jumpTo - (DWORD)finalAddr) - 5;

*finalAddr = 0xE9;
*((DWORD*)finalAddr + 0x1) = relAdr;

VirtualProtect(finalAddr, 5, oldProtect, &bkpProtect);
```

`allocAddr` is the address for the code-cave i have allocated above.
Now while debugging it i can see that `relAddr` is `0xFFFABBF9` which seems really high to me. But if i look into the disassembly view of Visual Studio the `jmp` created leads to `0xF9939B14` which leads to an Access Violation Exception. I would believe that even if the jmp would lead to the "correct" address it would also throw an Exception. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can't call out from your hook proc (dynASM) to other code that you haven't copied (testCall) and if you did copy that as well you would not be able to call any RTL functions (std::cout) from it because that's either not present or at a different address in the hooked process.

Comment: To go off of what @500-InternalServerError said, the `call` instructions use relative addressing. Instead, you should just load the absolute address into a register, and "call" that register.

Comment: Oh. Does that not work, even if both are actually inside the same process memory space? Notice that i do inject and hook into the same process i start the injecting and hooking from.

@DrewMcGowen I am trying to inject a jmp call (0xE9 = jmp, isn't it?) and as far as i can remember jmp are using relative addresse, aren't they? Thanks for any suggestions so far.

Comment: @puelo `jmp` and `call`, in the immediate offset form, are relative jumps. In the effective address form, they are absolute.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Sorry i don't really know what u mean. Can u elaborate a little bit?
And what about my first sentence. Am i unable to call the function (testCall), even if both are actually in the same process memory space, as described above? I only use one process!

Comment: If you are patching the current process then you can of course call RTL functions within it, as long as you get the address arithmetic right, but what would be the point?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Just for practice. I am only playing around and look at the disassembly etc. I figured that it would be easier if i created my own test application for this.

Comment: @puelo you're able to call the function, but it's because of the relative jump problems that it doesn't work. Basically, a relative jump adds some number to the program counter to compute the new destination. An absolute jump discards the old value of the program counter and loads a new value.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Ok. How do i know if a jmp or call is absolute or relative? Or is a call always absolute and a jmp always relative? Thanks

Comment: @puelo as I mentioned earlier, a call or jmp to a symbol or an immediate offset (i.e. a constant number) is relative; all others are absolute

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Ok got it. I hook to the function and write a 0xE9 opcode for the jmp in the first byte and then a address into the following 4 bytes. But why does this address value change? If i look into the normal debugger i see an address like 0x00030000, but if i look into the disassembly, i see that the address is something like 0x0FB19B14....